# Replacing a 1200v 8A fast switching diode that is obsolete

Tags: diodes

In order to evaluate (power up <1hr) and aircraft power converter. There are 2 leaky of 8 "Stealth Diodes" That are rated 1200v 8A and are hi-frequency switching diodes in a TO-220 PACKAGE, obsolete.

question: What in my extensive parts bin could I temporarily cross these diodes with? ie TV horizontal barrier diode etc

Data sheet link  http://www.alldatasheet.com/view.jsp?Searchword=Isl9r8120p2

Comment: Virtually impossible to say with no knowledge of the design

Comment: There are other sources for old inventory of ISL9R8120P2, like https://www.aliexpress.com/item/10PCS-New-original-ISL9R8120P2-R8120P2-TO-220-2-fast-recovery-1200V-8A/32488416936.html or http://www.soniccraft.com/product_info.php/fairchild-stealth-diode-8a1200v-p-1934

Comment: I'm never getting on a plane again.

Comment: The part still exists but only in SMT which is cheaper and better for a board level heatsink, but depending on your ability to improvise may not be possible.  How much leakage are you getting? https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/on-semiconductor/ISL9R18120S3ST/ISL9R18120S3STTR-ND/1057335 Mouser has the TO220 in stock https://ca.mouser.com/ProductDetail/ON-Semiconductor-Fairchild/RHRP8120-F102?qs=sGAEpiMZZMtbRapU8LlZD1mYH2WwMoca0KcGWJLRy0PjQGDlszX97Q%3d%3d

Comment: @Wossname Why so few upvotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mouser has the TO220 in [stock at mouser](https://ca.mouser.com/ProductDetail/ON-Semiconductor-Fairchild/RHRP8120-F102?qs=sGAEpiMZZMtbRapU8LlZD1mYH2WwMoca0KcGWJLRy0PjQGDlszX97Q%3D%3D)

I suggest you stock up in spares.

Comment: It looks like a different part number, RHRP8120-F102...but fairly close. Reverse recovery time differs 2X.

Comment: same PIV leakage and pF though

Answer (score 2):

Repairing and replacing power elements in power converters is a tricky business. In a professional design all components around power switches are designed/tuned to have least possible dissipation in transistors. The switching is usually designed to avoid "active region" of a switch (where the most transient dissipation occurs), and provide something like shown in green in the picture below.
[image]
So the complementary parts of high-power switch (diodes and snubber circuits) should carefully match the original components, reverse recovery charge and time, dynamic impedance, etc. A "better" diode might be not the most efficient one without additional circuit tuning. Otherwise the power transistors would go into "puff" in no time. You probably should consult with On semi/Fairchild about EXACT replacement part.

Comment: Thank you  Ali, I agree. Being in series prior to Mosfet switching I though I could sneak something in to determine if other components could drag out equipment downtime. I was surprised to find places like Ebay are dumping grounds for NOS semis and found a must buy qty50 source